# What does removal from site for reasons of moderation mean

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, bug, close-reasons

When I went to search for this question: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/74217/is-equality-as-a-political-goal-meaningless/74227#74227, which had earlier been closed, I was confronted by a large numeral "404," and told "This question was removed from Philosophy Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation." Clicking on certain links one gets a "Page not found - Philosophy Stack Exchange" message.

What does it mean for a question to be removed for "reasons of moderation?"  Why was this entire question, its answers and comments to all removed?

What are the criteria for complete removal, erasure, on, irony of ironies, a cite dedicated to philosophy. (Even @J D, who has here been rightfully railing against seemingly arbitrary [though often ostensibly ideologically motivated] closure, has, to my knowledge, said nothing about "removal.")

Answer (score 4):

> What does it mean for a question to be removed for "reasons of moderation?" Why was this entire question, its answers and comments to all removed?

There are basically two ways for a question to be removed: voluntarily by its author, and for reasons of moderation. That's a very broad indication; one of the reasons may be that the question was [removed automatically by a process nicknamed 'Roomba'](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). I can't see the question, but you could check if it qualifies for this process.

Comment: It is exactly what happened here: "This post is hidden. It was automatically deleted 4 months ago by Community"